# How to cede coalition's allies' provinces (or offer any tribute from their pockets, really)

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I was in a game where I was the coalition leader with another country, facing against another coalition whose war goal was to conquer one of my allies' provinces (which they did).
How do I force my ally to cede the province and end the war?
It seems I can only offer tribute from my own country (give my ducets, cancel my treaties, etc.) but can make no demands for my allies.
I also couldn't find a way to leave the coalition, which meant that there was no way for me to lose the war, as I couldn't offer anything the enemy coalition wanted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. I tend to avoid coalitions and wars for the same reasons. Being in a war you're not leading sucks. If you win, you'll likely get nothing for your efforts, and if you're loosing, the war leader might take ages to give up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your coalition partners opted out of allowing the coalition leader to negotiate for them. Which would result in what you describe. Not being able to cede fellow coalition members provinces etc.

This bit me when I did the opposite and forgot to untick the 'leader can negotiate for us' tick box. I got pulled into a war by Scotland when I was Ireland and Scotland ceded Meath to England in a peace deal before I could get my armies in a position to help.

The following is a fairly good description of coalition mechanics when at war.

Taken from the EU4 wiki -

**Coalitions in war**

- The coalition call-to-arms is an automatic one and will result in all members with or without a truce with the target and not currently at war with another coalition member instantly being part of the war. There is no option to decline.
- Each coalition has a war leader. If the coalition is attacking, the war leader is the country that declared war. If the coalition is defending, the war leader is the most powerful nation in the coalition (determined how?)
- The war leader always negotiates for the entire coalition; unlike alliances, countries in a coalition cannot make a separate peace. This means that if countries opt out of allowing the leader of a coalition to negotiate for them they will not be a way to gain provinces from them in that specific war.
- Occupying all of the provinces of a member of a coalition will allow a country to ask for that member as a vassal in the peace deal.
- War leaders may call non-coalition allies into the war, but these allies are not bound by the coalition rules - they may decline the call, and can sign a separate peace with the enemy.